# Python: Kivy starts automatically whenever help('modules') is called

Tags: python, kivy

I've just installed **Kivy** and noticed that it somehow automatically starts if I call `help('modules')`.

This happens although I haven't imported the *module*.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That's a known (though amusing) bug:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1445

It dates from 2013, so probably it's not easy to fix but you can always put some pressure in git issues section.

Answer (score 1):

`help('modules')` works by walking the whole package tree of your Python installation and either reading the source (if the module is pure Python and has source code available), or loading it into the interpreter if it is an extension (or a Python module without source).

There is also another case in `pkg_util.walk_packages`, which will import packages. If either the package or the extension import has a sideeffect, it will be triggered by `help('modules')`.

One possible workaround is to black out the offending module in `sys.modules`, though of course this is not a solution:

```
def myhelp(*args):
  sys.modules['offender'] = None
  help(*args)
  sys.modules.pop('offender')
```

All you need to know is the name of the offending module (`kivy`?). You could even put this code into your `sitecustomize.py` and override the builtin `help` function.

The correct solution of course is to fix upstream, since sideeffects on module imports are generally a bad thing (since they can have all kind of ... well, sideeffects).